# cURL request not as expected. Request fails

Tags: curl

I have the following scrippt (snippet):

```sh
# URL to save
curl -s -i -b cookies.txt  -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form" https://www.myhosttech.eu/user-dns/zonesave
```

this request should be "application/x-www-form" but the request is performed as json. According to the documentation this shouldn't be the case.

The output loooks like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 20 Sep 2016 20:14:25 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 67
Content-Type: application/json
```

Any ideas?

**Edit**

```sh
curl -s -i -b cookies.txt  -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form" --data-raw @temp.txt https://www.myhosttech.eu/user-dns/zonesave
```

I can't save the data from temp.txt.

temp.txt I copied from HTTP Header insnpection

Comment: Uhm, I might be missing something here, but to me your output looks like the response from the server not the request to the server. What is the problem exactly? Does the request do the wrong thing, or are you getting back the wrong thing?

Comment: You miss the 'data' part, required in your command, like `-d 'foo=bar&base=qux'`

Comment: curl -s -i -b cookies.txt -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form" --data-raw @temp.txt myhosttech.eu/user-dns/zonesave same result. temp.txt is exactly copued from HTTP Header inspectio